# Prove that a monotonic sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent if and only if it is bounded.

Tags: analysis

I am studying for my exam in Analysis where I have to prove that above Propisition. The first implication is easy and does not cause any problems.

However when I have to prove that other implication that a boundend and monotonic sequence is convergent it gets a bit tricky.

I know that we use contradiction to prove the implication, thus we neglect that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \geq N \Rightarrow |a_k-a| < \epsilon$ which is not a problem. However, now my book says that we have to create a new stricly increasing sequence of integers recursively which we define as $(k_j)_{j=1}^\infty$.

Thus to prove that it is increasing we let $N = 1$ where we obtain $k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a_k-a \geq \epsilon$. Now we pick $N = k_{j-1} + 1$ to find that $k_j \geq k_{j-1} +1 > k_j$ which the book says is increasing but I dont understand this at all. Is this a typo? Should it have been $k_j \geq k_{j-1} +1 > k_{j-1}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this kind of theorem,  I think it is easier to use the term sup and inf of a bounded set of real numbers...

Comment: proposition, negate, strictly.

Comment: This is how the professor in the course has written the proof in our book but I do not understand how he proves that the new sequence is increasing ..

Comment: He probably means (but I'm guessing, as I don't have the text, is it online?) $k_j \ge k_{j-1}+1$ as a step in a recursion. This ensures the *indices* are increasing, not the corresponding values.

Comment: Where does the $a$ come from in your text?

Comment: Hi Henno. This is from my book. I hope it is readable. https://imgur.com/a/MFWmsD6

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a bounded monotonic sequence $S=(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ in $\Bbb R$ is convergent:

(1). If $S$ is increasing, i.e. $m<n\implies a_m\le a_n.$ Let $L=\sup \{a_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$

(1*). For any $m\in \Bbb N$ we have $\sup \{a_n:n> m\}=L.$ (See Footnote.)

Let $k_1=\min \{n:|a_n-L|<1\},$ which exists by def'n of $L.$

Let $k_{j+1}=\min \{n>k_j:|a_n-L|<1/(j+1)\}.$ Note that $k_{j+1}$ exists by (1*) with $m=k_j,$ and by the def'n of $\sup \{a_n:n> m\}.$

Given $d>0,$ take $j\in \Bbb N$ with $1/j\le d.$ Now  we have $$ n\ge k_j \implies L-d\le L-1/j<a_{k_j}\le a_n\le L\implies |L-a_n|<d.$$

(2). If $S$ is  not increasing, then $S'=(-a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is bounded, monotonic, and increasing, so we have by (1) that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(-a_n)=L'$ exists, so $-L'=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n.$

Footnote. If $S$ is increasing then the set $B$ of upper bounds for $\{a_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ is equal to the set $B_m$ of upper bounds for  $\{a_n:n> m\},$ so $\sup \{a_n:n> m\}=\min B_m=\min B=L.$

Comment: I don't think the OP will appreciate comments about the axiom of choice at this level though.

Comment: @user661541 I re-wrote it, as I had originally answered the opposite implication, which the OP said was the easy part.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_n)$ is monotonic (I'll assume increasing for definiteness) and bounded, then

$$L=\sup \{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$$ is a well-defined real number.

Now if $\varepsilon >0$, then $L-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound for $\{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ (as $L$ is the *smallest* upper bound by definition) and so for some $N$ we have $x_N > L-\varepsilon$. By monotonicity we have

$$\forall n \ge N: x_n \ge x_N > L-\varepsilon$$

so that

$$\forall n \ge N: x_n \in (L-\varepsilon, L+\varepsilon)$$

which shows that $x_n \to L$ as $\varepsilon >0$ was arbitrary. The decreasing case uses the $\inf$ instead and is very similar.

Comment: Hi Henno. Thanks. But I really want to understand the proof my professor has written in our book, so I understand this. He uses what I have written to prove that the new sequence is stricly increasing but I dont understand it. I know that we end up having that $L-\epsilon$ is an upper bound which is the contradiction that completes the proof but I need to understand how he proves that the new sequence he creates is stricly increasing. Thanks.

Comment: @MathiasNissen I don't have your text book, and I don't understand the argument you were trying to sketch so I gave a simple and direct argument for the increasing case, the decreasing case is similar using $\inf$. I don't see how a strictly increasing sequence would be a contradiction in your sketch.